# Can Swift func() return multiple values to an Objective-C caller?

Tags: swift

If I have a Swift func defined thusly:

```
func hilo (holeSize : Int, prompt : Int) -> (ballType : Int, ballColor : Int)) {

...
return (result1, result2)

}
```

Is there any way to call this Swift func from an Objective-C method?  I was hoping to call the func from Objective-C using an array or dictionary of sorts to receive the func result.

Can't seem to find any doco or other that discusses this topic.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tuples (function that returns multiple value) are not supported in Objective-C but you can use block for that.

```
- (void)hilo:(int)holeSize prompt:(int)prompt callback:(void (^)(ballType : Int, ballColor : Int))result {
   ...
}


[self hilo:(int)holeSize prompt:(int)prompt callback:^(ballType : Int, ballColor : Int) {
   ....
}];
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of how the Swift func should be changed to accommodate a block? i.e. what would the Swift func look like, and what would the obj-c method look like?

Answer (score 3):

You can't. You'll have to rework your Swift method to return a type that is valid in Objective-C.

From: Apple Inc. [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C.](https://itun.es/us/1u3-0.l) iBooks.

> You’ll have access to anything within a class or protocol that’s marked with the @objc attribute as long as it’s compatible with Objective-C. This excludes Swift-only features such as those listed here:
>
> - Generics
> - Tuples
> - Enumerations defined in Swift
> - Structures defined in Swift
> - Top-level functions defined in Swift
> - Global variables defined in Swift
> - Typealiases defined in Swift
> - Swift-style variadics
> - Nested types
> - Curried functions
>
> For example, a method that takes a generic type as an argument or
>   **returns a tuple will not be usable from Objective-C**.

Emphasis mine

Answer (score 1):

By @ikmal-ezzani 's ideal.  I make a implemention detail as bellow:

**Swift code:**

```
func getResult(_ input: Int) -> (previous: Int, next: Int) {
    return (previous: input - 1, next: input + 1)
}

@objc class WrapClass: NSObject {
    @objc static func getResult(_ input: Int, callback: ((_ previous: Int, _ next: Int) -> Void)) {
        let (previous, next) = YourModel.getResult(input)
        callback(previous, next)
    }
}
```

**Object-C code:**

```
//to use in Object-C
__block NSInteger pre = 0;
__block NSInteger next = 0;
[WrapClass getResult:10 callback:^(NSInteger preValue, NSInteger nextValue) {
    pre = preValue;
    next = nextValue;
}];
```